# Warning: Legacy context API has been detected within a strict-mode tree

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

**The old API will be supported in all 16.x releases, but applications using it should migrate to the new version.
Please update the following components: Transition.**

when I tried to use react. strict mode but the warning still appear on the console.log chrome browser I am using reactstrab components (like Card, Modal) in react

Comment: which version of reactstrap are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the index.js
remove the React.StrictMode tag like the following code

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />
document.getElementById('root')
);
```